# How to properly use default values for properties on Angular 11 / TS 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11, typescript4.0

I researched a lot but couldn't find out what happened with default properties on angular 11/TS4.

For example, on Angular 10 / TS 3, this worked just fine:

```
export class MyDirective {
    @Input() isRange = false;
}
```

Consumer TS

```
isRange?: boolean;
```

Consumer HTML

```
<div myDirective [isRange]="isRange"></div>
```

I was able to set `isRange` as an optional property and it would work, which makes perfect sense, since the default attribution should indeed assume that for any empty value, it would use its default. That's how it happens on other languages, anyway...

But now, after migrating to angular 11/TS4, the same code generates the error:

> error TS2322: Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
>
> 9         [isRange]="isRange"

The error only goes away after I change the input to:

```
@Input() isRange?= false;
```

I'm always referring to angular 11/TS4 because even though I truly thinks this was caused by TS, I couldn't quite be sure of that while researching.

My question is, why is the `?` now required for properties with default values, and most important, does it work the same way? For instance, just by adding the `?` would it set the default `false` value if I insert `undefined`?

I'd really love a way to return to the previous (IMO correct) behavior, without deactivating any important checks, like `strictTemplateCheck`. Because even though the project builds (though I'm not sure this is the right way to go), I still have to use a lot of `!` in my code now, to let TS know the property should have a value.

**If you know where it is, please add the doc link to your answer/comment.**

And please let me know if anything is not clear.

Thanks!

Comment: Typescript is set to strict Mode, and the variable you are passing to your input seems it can potentially be undefined. Typescript checks this if the mode is set to strict.

Comment: @pascalpuetz yes, but that should be acceptable. If a property has a default value, it should accept undefined. Right?

Comment: no, you have to explicitly allow `undefined` to be passed as well. In strict mode, `boolean` and `boolean | undefined` are different types and `boolean` cannot be `undefined` except when it is explicitly allowed. This is to reduce errors like `Property 'x' is not present on 'undefined'` issues - since in strict mode you have to explicitly check for this. This is seperate from the fact that Angular still assigns the default value - Typescript does not know that, which is why you have to add the bang operator `!`, which effectively tells TS "I know this will never be undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this behavor was introduced in TS v4 https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#class-property-inference-from-constructors

both `?` and `!` are ok if you're sure `undefined` values are handled well

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link! There's still an unanswered question, though. The link you provided, doesn't tell me if `isRange?=false` will use false as default when I do `[isRange]=undefined`. From it I could read about type inference, but not default values. Thanks again.

Comment: `[isRange]=undefined` will take `false` as a default value, Typescript will not change the old behavior without mentioning it, this new change is just a type safety measure

Comment: Cool, thanks. I just wish I could revert to not using the `?` that forces me to use `!` inside the component... hopefully this is bugging others as well and they'll provide an alternative. Thanks again.